# Horizontal scroll View not scroll?

Tags: react-native, expo, native-base

i am working with a react native project but i have a problem that is my horizontal scroll view dont want to scroll it working with ios but android no, i am working with native base tabs so i have two screens the first with vertical scrolling works fine but the second with horizontal dont work do you have any idea ? i tried to add nestedScrollEnabled props but not working

tabs code

```
 <Tabs
   tabBarUnderlineStyle={tabBarUnderlineStyle}
   tabContainerStyle={tabContainerStyle}>
   <Tab
     heading={strings.info}
     tabStyle={tabStyle}
     activeTabStyle={tabStyle}
     textStyle={textStyle}
     activeTextStyle={activeTextStyle}>
     <Info />
   </Tab>
   <Tab
     heading={strings.state}
     tabStyle={tabStyle}
     activeTabStyle={tabStyle}
     textStyle={textStyle}
     activeTextStyle={activeTextStyle}>
     <State />
   </Tab>
 </Tabs>
```

and here is the screen that i have problem with

```
 <View style={container}>
   <View style={itemsContainer}>
     <View>
       <ScrollView horizontal nestedScrollEnabled={true}>
         <HeaderItem label={Strings.ca} />
         <HeaderItem label={Strings.packs} />
         <HeaderItem label={Strings.terme} />
         <HeaderItem label={Strings.sinistre} />
         <HeaderItem label={Strings.attestation} />
       </ScrollView>
     </View>
   </View>
 </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { TabViewAnimated, TabViewPage, TabBarTop } from 'react-native-tab-view';

export default class TabViewExample extends Component {
  state = {
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      { key: '1', title: 'First' },
      { key: '2', title: 'Second' },
    ],
  };

  _renderScene = ({ route }) => {
    switch (route.key) {
    case '1':
      return <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ff4081' }} />;
    case '2':
      return <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#673ab7' }} />;
    default:
      return null;
    }
  };

  _renderPage = (props) => <TabViewPage {...props} renderScene={this._renderScene} />;

  render() {
    return (
      <TabViewAnimated
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        navigationState={this.state.navigation}
        renderScene={this._renderPage}
        renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
        onRequestChangeTab={index => this.setState({ index })}
      />
    );
  }
}
```